# Add non-gac assemblies to visual studio project and item template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, itemtemplate, project-template

I have seen the examples of adding references to assemblies from GAC to visual studio 2010 project or item templates. Is it possible to add references to non-GAC assemblies in my custom project or item templates?

I have all our common assemblies stored in local folder (in dev environment) that I want to reference in my custom project and item templates. How can I do it?

```xml
<Reference>        
  <Assembly>MyWebUtils, Version=8.3.842.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=</Assembly> 
</Reference>
```

When I try to add local dlls, I get error saying that it can't reference the assemblies.